# как распарсить данные внутри тэга script

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x

подскажите, пжл, как на python3 распарсить данные внутри тэга script?
исходная страница вот по этому адресу  http://www.opeo.ru/01.01.05.01/member_list.aspx
мне нужно получить список url-ов для каждого действующего оценщика.
проблема в том, что этого списка нет в HTML коде страницы, этот список подгружается с помощью JS.

с помощью BS я могу получить любой из тэгов script.

```
def get_page_data(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    script = soup.find_all('script')
    for s in script:
        print(s)
```

но я не понимаю, как мне залезть вовнутрь тэга script и получить из него данные?
подскажите, пжл, где и что почитать на эту тему?
буду очень благодарен.

Comment: 1. Приведите пример кода, из которого необходимо извлечь  данные. 2. Из js данные можно извлечь только средствами js. Остальное нецелесообразно. Для подобного можно использовать selenium

Answer (score 0):

url-ы каждого оценщика я с горем пополам достал.
в отладчике нашел `url` из которого грузится `html` с таблицей и распарсил ее с помощью BS

вот этот `url`

http://nbase.opeo.ru/api/app/member_list_app.aspx?card=/01.01.05.01/member_card.aspx&css=/Content/register.css

но теперь столкнулся с другой проблемой.

я получил 439 url-ов
каждый выглядит вот так

http://nbase.opeo.ru/api/app/member_card_app.aspx?id=9043c33f-770f-4a6c-827e-a59f0109a8ca&card=/01.01.05.01/member_card.aspx&css=/Content/register.css

когда я пытаюсь любой из этих url-ов прогнать через парсер, чтобы получить дополнительные сведения, полученные url-ы у меня подменяются.

вот код

```
def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text

def get_page_data(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    table = soup.find('table', class_='table-member-list').find('tbody').find_all('tr')    
    for i in range(len(table)):
        persons_url = 'http://nbase.opeo.ru/01.01.05.01/member_card.aspx'
        persons_id = table[i].find_all('td')[1].find('a').get('data-id')
        persons_card = '/01.01.05.01/member_card.aspx'
        persons_css = '/Content/register.css'
        params = {'id':persons_id,
                  'card':persons_card,
                  'css':persons_css}
        headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0'}
        req = requests.get(persons_url, params=params, headers=headers)
        persons_html = req.text
        persons_soup = BeautifulSoup(persons_html, 'lxml')
        name = persons_soup.find('h1').text.strip()
        print(name)

def main():
    url = 'http://nbase.opeo.ru/api/app/member_list_app.aspx?card=/01.01.05.01/member_card.aspx&css=/Content/register.css'
    get_page_data(get_html(url))
```

print(name) - в качестве теста, чтобы убедиться, что код работает.
он должен выводить имя, но выводит другой текст.
начинаю выяснять почему и вижу, что в функции `get_html(url)` идет подмена url-а
он вставляется такой
http://nbase.opeo.ru/access/loginform.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f01.01.05.01%2fmember_card.aspx%3fid%3d7829ce9b-fa70-46ca-9d71-abe600cf2e11%26card%3d%2f01.01.05.01%2fmember_card.aspx%26css%3d%2fContent%2fregister.css&id=7829ce9b-fa70-46ca-9d71-abe600cf2e11&card=/01.01.05.01/member_card.aspx&css=/Content/register.css

начинаю смотреть html всей страницы и вижу там такой кусок кода

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                document.domain = "opeo.ru";
                var key = getParameterByName("id");

                var url = "/api/app/member_card_app.aspx";
                var s = "http://nbase.opeo.ru" + url + "?"
                    + "id=" + key
                    + "&"
                    + "card=/01.01.05.01/member_card.aspx&css=/Content/register.css"
                ;

                //console.log(s);
                $("#f").attr("src", s).appendTo("#xframe").iFrameResize();
                $("article").iFrameResize();
                ;
            });


            function getParameterByName(name, url) {
                if (!url) url = window.location.href;
                name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
                var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
                    results = regex.exec(url);
                if (!results) return null;
                if (!results[2]) return '';
                return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
            }


        </script>
```

я еще только начинаю осваивать питона, а тут еще js на мою голову.
я так понимаю, именно этот скрипт перебрасывает меня с нужной страницы на форму регистрации.
кто-то может пояснить, как обойти это в парсере и получить html  нужной мне страницы?
ведь если я нужный мне url тупо вставляю в окно браузера, все нормально грузится